# Maximum number of dice that can be put straight (Haskell) [Old]

Tags: haskell, optimization

This problem involves an arbitrary number of dice with each an arbitrary number of sides. We then find the maximal number of dice that can be put in a straight, see [Google's Code Jam explanation](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000876ff1/0000000000a46471). I've been trying to solve the problem in Haskell and I think the following solution works algorithmically. However, it is not fast enough to earn full points on the problem, so can this be optimized?

```
import Data.List (sort)

getMaxStraight :: [Int] -> Int
getMaxStraight sides =
  foldl
    (\maxStraight side -> if side > maxStraight then succ maxStraight else maxStraight)
    0
    (sort sides)
```

Aside from this, I've also written a Python solution which did run in time. What is going on?

```py
def solve(sides)
    sides = sorted(sides)
    max_straight = 0
    for side in sides:
        if side > max_straight:
            max_straight += 1
    return max_straight
```

*Edit: This post has been "reverted" to an older version. A newer version of the post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71894282/python-faster-than-haskell-in-a-code-jam-problem-d1000000)*

Comment: What if you use [**`foldl'`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl-39-)?

Comment: What's the point of `min_side` in the Python code? You never use it.

Comment: It'd be better if you'd closed this entry and posted the new one as a new post with the updated code. It'll get more views that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are here doing is constructing a large expression tree that will look for a list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` as:

```
f (f (f (f (f (f 0 1) 2) 3) 4) 5) 6
```

with `f` the lambda expression `\maxStraight side -> if side > maxStraight then succ maxStraight else maxStraight`. You thus will first create a large expression that will likely take considerable memory, and then evaluate that.

As the [documentation on **`foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`** says](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl):

> If you want an efficient strict left-fold, you probably want to use [`foldl'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl-39-) instead of [`foldl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl). The reason for this is that the latter does not force the inner results (e.g. `` z `f` x1 `` in the above example) before applying them to the operator (e.g. to `` (`f` x2) ``). This results in a thunk chain *(n)* elements long, which then must be evaluated from the outside-in.

By using [**`foldl' :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl-39-), for each step, the result will be evaluated to [*Weak Head Normal Form (WHNF)* <sup>[haskell-wiki]</sup>](https://wiki.haskell.org/Weak_head_normal_form), and thus you prevent creating a large thunk. You can implement this like:

```
import Data.Foldable(foldl')

getMaxStraight :: [Int] -> Int
getMaxStraight sides =
  foldl'
    (\maxStraight side -> if side > maxStraight then succ maxStraight else maxStraight)
    0
    (sort sides)
```