# Python faster than Haskell in a Code Jam problem? (d1000000)

Tags: performance, haskell, optimization, dice

This problem involves an arbitrary number of dice with each an arbitrary number of sides. We then find the maximal number of dice that can be put in a straight, see [Google's Code Jam explanation](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000876ff1/0000000000a46471). The implementation should be reasonably efficient for around `10^5` dice with each one having up to `10^6` sides.

I've been trying to solve the problem in Haskell and this is my solution. However, it is not fast enough to earn full points on the problem, so can this be optimized?

```hs
import Data.List (sort)
import Data.Foldable (foldl')

getMaxStraight :: [Int] -> Int
getMaxStraight sides =
  foldl'
    (\maxStraight side -> if side > maxStraight then succ maxStraight else maxStraight)
    0
    (sort sides)

-- Doing IO in Haskell
-- Assuming the above works perfectly, something might not perform well below

main :: IO ()
main = do
  line <- getLine :: IO String
  let numberOfCases = read line :: Int
   in mapM_ solveCase [1 .. numberOfCases]

solveCase :: Show a => a -> IO ()
solveCase i = do
  line1 <- getLine :: IO String
  line2 <- getLine :: IO String
  let numberOfDice = read line1 :: Int
  let diceSides = map read (words line2) :: [Int]
  let maxStraight = getMaxStraight diceSides
  putStrLn $ "Case #" ++ show i ++ ": " ++ show maxStraight
```

Aside from this, I've also written a Python solution which did run in time. I'd expect that Haskell would run faster than Python. What is going on?

```py
def get_max_straight(sides):
    max_straight = 0
    for side in sorted(sides):
        if side > max_straight:
            max_straight += 1
    return max_straight

# Doing IO in Python
# This works as needed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tests_len = int(input())
    for case_num in range(1, 1 + tests_len):
        input() # Discard unneeded input
        sides = [int(s) for s in input().split(' ')]
        print(f'Case #{case_num}: {get_max_straight(sides)}')
```

Comment: Looks like the overall performance should be dominated by how fast `sort` / `sorted` perform. Haskell's standard `sort` is a native list implementation and not particularly optimised, you may get faster runtimes with something from [vector-algorithms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms). Apart from that: is the code compiled with `-O2`? GHC doesn't generate fast code if optimisations aren't enabled.

Comment: I enabled optimisations by prepending the pragma `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}`, which wasn't enough. Apparently, Haskell uses **merge sort** and Python uses **Timsort**, both of which have average performance complexity `O(n log n)`. Maybe using a algorithm like Radix sort would solve the problem, although external packages cannot be accessed in Code Jam.

Comment: As pointed above, the issue is (likely) not in the algorithm but in the data structure. Don't use `sort` on anywhere large lists, use vectors and vector-algorithms instead.

Comment: Python's built in lists are (mutable) arrays. Haskell's built in lists are linked lists. The difference between mergesort and Timsort isn't particularly relevant, nor the general execution speed difference between Haskell and Python; Timsort would probably not be fast enough on linked lists in Python either. I did this problem in Haskell too and ran into exactly the same problem, but couldn't find an off-the-shelf sort for `Data.Vector` in the package set Code Jam uses. I ended up with an algorithm that doesn't require sorting (but did still use a mutable vector).

Comment: Code Jam compiles Haskell files with this command: ` ghc +RTS -V0 -RTS -rtsopts -O2 -o Solution Solution.hs` (according to [the FAQ](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/faq)). So it was already using `-O2`, no need for the pragma.